# Comparing Access Timestamps

Tags: ms-access

I have this query, but i can't figure out why it won't work.  The releveant timestamps are

```
source_date_time_stamp = 6/02/2015 12:56:01 AM
destin_date_time_stamp = 5/22/2015 12:56:01 AM
```

Relevant SQL query

```
SQL = "SELECT source_db.date_time_stamp as source_date_time_stamp," & _
        "source_db.review_matter_id as source_review_matter_id, " & _
        "source_db.in_sample as source_in_sample, " & _
        "source_db.[Short Name] as source_short_name, " & _
        "source_db.[Title Line 1] AS source_title_line_1, " & _
        "source_db.Completed AS source_completed, " & _
        "source_db.[DDF Rating] AS source_statement_date, " & _
        "source_db.[Total Assets] AS source_total_assets, " & _
        "source_db.[Liquid Assets] AS source_liquid_assets, " & _
        "source_db.Liabilities AS source_liabilities, " & _
        "source_db.[Net Worth] AS source_net_worth, " & _
        "source_db.[Gurantor Statement Date] AS source_guarantor_statment_date, " & _
        "source_db.[Gurantor Total Assets] AS source_guar_total_assets," & _
        "source_db.[Gurantor Liabilities] AS source_guar_liablities," & _
        "source_db.[Gurantor Net Worth] AS source_guar_net_worth, " & _
        "destin_db.date_time_stamp AS destin_date_time_stamp " & _
        "FROM (borrowers source_db " & _
        "LEFT JOIN borrowers destin_db " & _
        "ON source_db.review_matter_id = destin_db.review_matter_id " & _
        "AND source_db.borrower_id = destin_db.borrower_id" & _
        ") IN  '" & sourceDB & "' " & _
        "WHERE source_db.date_time_stamp > destin_db.date_time_stamp"
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the timestamps are stored as strings rather than in native date/time formats for Access.  Either convert them to date/time formats or store them in the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS format.

Comment: They are stored as Date/Time.

Comment: Explain how the query does not work.  Sample data and actual/desired results are quite helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I expect to get back one result. All the data I need from source, with those two timestamps.  I can successfully, get back the data I want without the where clause (of course i get all records on the tables that match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateDiff:

```
"WHERE DateDiff("s", source_db.date_time_stamp, destin_db.date_time_stamp) > 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

One hack that I sometimes use for a quick and dirty solution is to convert the timestamp values into numeric values using the cdbl() function. It lets you see whether the logic expected is being applied independent of the date convention.

```
'Your example dates in your question results in 
'source_date_time_stamp =    42,157.0388888889 
'destin_date_time_stamp =    42,146.0389004630
```

The where statement would be as below:

```
"WHERE cdbl(source_db.date_time_stamp) > cdbl(destin_db.date_time_stamp)"
```

Aside from that